# why slider is not working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

could you please tell me why slider is not working in jquery ?
i see this demo , but it callback function not fire ?
why ?

I take help from this url
http://rangeslider.js.org/

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <input type="range" min="10"
           max="1000"
           step="10"
           value="300" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            console.log('====')
            $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
                // Feature detection the default is `true`.
                // Set this to `false` if you want to use
                // the polyfill also in Browsers which support
                // the native <input type="range"> element.
                polyfill: true,

                // Callback function
                onInit: function () {
                    console.log('init')
                },

                // Callback function
                onSlide: function (position, value) { },

                // Callback function
                onSlideEnd: function (position, value) {
                    console.log(value)
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/cbh60dJcvHhAoqDlLo9g?p=preview

callback function not fire why ? when I slide the slider

Answer (score 0):

From your example it's not clear whether you're loading the JS and CSS files for Range Slider, so that could be part of the problem.

Also, if you want it to show by default you need to change `polyfill: true,` to `polyfill: false,`.

```js
$(function () {
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
        polyfill: false,

        onInit: function() {
            console.log('init')
        },

        // Callback function
        onSlide: function(position, value) {},

        // Callback function
        onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {
            console.log(value)

        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.min.css">

<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<input type="range" min="10"
    max="1000"
    step="10"
    value="300"
/>
```

Comment: You're not loading the CSS needed for Range Slider, and you also need to set `polyfill: false`. You need to include the CSS that can be found here `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.min.css`